# How to create a line bar in Streamlit progress column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, streamlit

I have a DataFrame in Streamlit where I'm showing the **last closing stock price** relative to the **52 week low** and **52 week high**.

I'm using `ProgressColumn` ([Streamlit docs](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/data/st.column_config/st.column_config.progresscolumn)) to show the column but the issue is `column_config` has only one min and one max:

```py
st.data_editor(
            df,
            column_config={
                "ClosingPrice": st.column_config.ProgressColumn(
                    "ClosingPrice",
                    min_value=df["52WeekLow"].min(),
                    max_value=df["52WeekHigh"].max(),
                    format="$%.2f",
                ),
            },
        )
```

This doesn't work because the `min_value` and `max_value` is absolute for the whole DataFrame and not for each row.

Is there a way to display each row's min and max?  Maybe I can use a different tool to show this column in the DataFrame?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, a (*hacky?*) workaround would be to use pandas [*Styler*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.html) and incorporate its own progress [`bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.bar.html) :

```
s = (
    df.style.hide(axis=0)
        .format({"ClosingPrice": "${:.2f}"}, precision=2)
        .set_properties(subset=["ClosingPrice"], **{"text-align": "right"})
)

for r, (l, h) in enumerate(zip(df["52WeekLow"], df["52WeekHigh"])):
    s = s.bar(
        subset=pd.IndexSlice[r, "ClosingPrice"],
        vmin=l, vmax=h,
        color="lightgreen"
    )

st.markdown(s.to_html(), unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

Output (*in Streamlit*) :

[image]

Used input :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "52WeekLow": [1.21, 0.2006, 0.161, 0.1255, 1.07, 1.46, 1.16, 1.12, 1.82, 0.27],
        "ClosingPrice": [3.15, 0.21, 0.19, 0.13, 1.73, 3.0, 1.5, 2.98, 2.09, 1.07],
        "52WeekHigh": [21.0, 13.25, 1.75, 3.45, 5.4, 7.84, 8.7, 71.5, 6.064, 1.75],
    }
)
```

Comment: Very clever solution!  I'm learning new things :)  Does the Styler object automatically append the rows?  I'm talking about `s = s.bar(...)` .   I see it works without having to append.